# Use of Hashing Algorithm in Asymmetric Cryptographic Padding

Tags: python, cryptography, encryption-asymmetric

I'm using Python Cryptography library, and performing asymmetric encryption.

I'm referring to [this example](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric/rsa/#encryption).

```
>>> message = b"encrypted data"
>>> ciphertext = public_key.encrypt(
...     message,
...     padding.OAEP(
...         mgf=padding.MGF1(algorithm=hashes.SHA256()),
...         algorithm=hashes.SHA256(),
...         label=None
...     )
... )
```

I understand what padding does. However, I can't relate to **why SHA256() is used?**

Answer (score 3):

RSA encryption is based on the RSA [trapdoor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trapdoor_function) permutation: a transformation which is easy to perform in one direction, but infeasible in the other direction unless you know a “magic” value (the private key). Turning a trapdoor function into an encryption scheme is not easy. For a start, it's vital that the encryption is *non-deterministic*: otherwise, if someone could guess what a message might be, they would be able to check their guess by performing the encryption (with the public key) and comparing with the ciphertext they want to break. To avoid this, encryption schemes always include some random part, called a *nonce*.

The RSA trapdoor operation takes input which has a fixed size, determined by the key. Basically, with an *n*-bit key, you need an (*n*-1)-bit input string. So to encrypt something, you need to build a string of the required length from the original message. The operation to assemble the payload to encrypt and the nonce and format them in a certain way is called *padding*. There are two standard padding mechanisms for RSA encryption: PKCS#1v1.5 and OAEP.

Including a random nonce is necessary, but not sufficient to make RSA encryption secure. The mathematical operation at the root of RSA has some “nice” mathematical properties. In many real-world situations, an attacker who wants to decrypt a ciphertext can [submit modified ciphertexts for decryption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adaptive_chosen_ciphertext_attack), and even if those ciphertexts are rejected as invalid, exactly how they're rejected (error messages, timing, …) can be enough to reconstruct the plaintext. This is a problem with PKCS#1v1.5 padding, which is vulnerable to oracle attacks such as [Bleichenbacher's attack](https://web.archive.org/web/20120204040056/http://www.bell-labs.com/user/bleichen/papers/pkcs.ps) and [Manger's attack](http://archiv.infsec.ethz.ch/education/fs08/secsem/Manger01.pdf) where the attacker generates modified ciphertexts and obtains information about their validity which eventually allows reconstructing the plaintext.

OAEP is designed to make it impossible for the attacker to generate useful ciphertexts. In a nutshell, it works by masking (with xor) the payload with a pseudorandom string. The standard way to generate this pseudorandom string is with a construction called MGF1, which starts from a seed and hashes it repeatedly. This masking breaks the mathematical relationships induced by the RSA exponentiation operation: modifying a ciphertext results in plaintexts that are wholly unrelated after unmasking. This way, if an attacker tries submitting modified ciphertexts, they'll just get decryption errors which don't provide any useful information to reconstruct the plaintext.

OAEP involves a second hash function to include a *label* in the encryption. The label is included in the mask calculation in such a way that attempting to decrypt with the wrong label results in a decryption error (in a way that doesn't reveal the correct label). The mask calculation uses the hash of the label. In practice, this feature is rarely used, and the label defaults to an empty string. Furthermore, in practice, everyone uses the same hash algorithm for the label and for the mask generation, but some libraries allow specifying a different hash.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the [Optimal Asymmetric Encryption Padding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimal_asymmetric_encryption_padding) ([OAEP.pdf](https://cseweb.ucsd.edu/%7Emihir/papers/oae.pdf)) design, you will see that it needs two hash functions `G` and `H` with different properties.

> G and H are typically some cryptographic hash functions fixed by the protocol.

These two are required for two different properties;

1. H hash function reduces the input into fixed size output.
2. G is [Mask generation function (MGF)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mask_generation_function) which uses a hash function to expand the input into a desired sized output. Is is defined in [rfc8017](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8017#appendix-B.2)